# How to pass and return a Stream using DataSnap in Delphi XE6?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

How to pass and return a Stream using DataSnap in Delphi XE6?

When I call my server side method, my stream is the correct class, has a size, and position. However, it when it comes accross to my client, the class is not what I expected, and it has no size or position

//Client side code

```
 procedure TForm1.brnGetReportClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      RunReportObj: TRunReportObject;
      S: TStream;
      FS: TFileStream;
    begin
       ....
       try
          S:= (ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.getReport(RunReportObj));
          //ShowMessage('Class = ' + S.ClassName + #10#13 +
          //            'Size = ' + intToStr(S.Size) + #10#13 +
          //            'Position = ' + intToStr(S.Position));
          S.Position:= 0;
          FS:= TFileStream.Create('test.rpt', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
          FS.Position:= 0;
          try
            FS.CopyFrom(S, S.Size);
          finally
            FS.Free;
          end;
        finally
          S.Free
        end;
    end;
```

My debugging showmessage in the code above, displays the following

```
Class = TDBXStreamReaderStream
Size = -1
Position = 0
```

//server side method

```
function getReport(const ARunReportObj: TRunReportObject): TStream;
var
  r: String;
  SS: TStringStream;
begin

   result:= TMemoryStream.Create;

   r := getRunReportJSON(ARunReportObj);
   SS := TStringStream.Create(r, TEncoding.ASCII);
   try
     try       
       ServerContainer1.idHttp1.Post
('https://imserver1.runit.com/isapi/isellitreporttest.dll/isellit', SS, result);
      ShowMessage('Class = ' + Result.ClassName + #10#13 +
                  'Size = ' + intToStr(result.Size) + #10#13 +
                  'Position = ' + intToStr(result.Position));
        Result.Position:= 0;
     except
     end;
   finally
    SS.Free;
   end;
end;
```

My debugging showmessage in the code above, displays the following

```
Class = TMemoryStream 
Size = 373760 
Position = 373760
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is as designed. DataSnap only guarantees that you get a `TStream` from the server, not which class it actually is. You can read from it, but that is it.

`Position = 0` is also expected, as that is what you set it in the server. On the other side, I am not sure if anything else as `Position = 0` is useful at all, so I would'nt be surprised if you get `Position = 0` on the client side anyway. Although, the stream my not start at the expected position when the server doesn't set it to 0 before.

For the `Size` property I refer to the `TStream` documentation:

> The Size property typically indicates the size of the stream in bytes. But a descendent of TStream can use -1 to indicate an unknown size. When the size is unknown, use the return value from TStream.Read to determine end of the stream.

You should be aware that DataSnap will not necessarily transfer the stream content with the call to `getReport`, but may do so when you call `Read` from the client side. This allows for something like endless streams like a movie or radio podcast.

Comment: thanks for responding. So, in order to fix my code (if possible?), I just need to use TStream.Read to get the size, or read it in chunks?

Comment: Your code suggests, that you want to store the whole stream to a file. You don't need the size to do that. If you give a 0 as the second parameter to CopyFrom, it will copy the whole stream. That is what the docs say: "If Count is 0, CopyFrom sets Source position to 0 before reading and then copies the entire contents of Source into the stream."

Answer (score 0):

**Server:**

client to server

```
function Tform_methodos.SendStream(st:TStream): string;
var sm : TMemoryStream;
begin
    ...
    sm:=TMemoryStream.create;
    sm.LoadFromStream(st);
    sm.SaveToFile(pasta+'\test.bin');
    sm.free;
end;
```

server to client:

```
function Tform_methodos.GetStream(var size : integer):Tstream;
begin
    ...
    result:=TmemoryStream.create;
    TmemoryStream(result).LoadFromFile('test.bin');
    size:=TmemoryStream(result).Size;
end;
```

**Client:**
client to server

```
var sm : TMemoryStream
    error : string;
begin
    ...
    sm:=TMemoryStream.create;
    sm.LoadFromFile('test.bin');
    error:=server.SendStream(sm);
    sm.Free;
end;
```

server to client

```
var sm : TmemoryStream;
    st : TStream;
    size : integer; 
begin
    ...
    sm:=TMemorystream.create;
    st:=server.GetStream(size);
    sm.CopyFrom(st,size);
    sm.SaveToFile('test.bin');
    sm.free;
end;
```